# How to install libqt4-webkit?

Tags: skype

New version of `Skype` requires `libqt4-webkit`, but when i trying to install it i get this error:

```
web@web-X501A1 ~ $ sudo apt-get install libqt4-webkit
[sudo] password for web: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt4-webkit
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,140 B of archives.
After this operation, 133 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libqt4-webkit
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe libqt4-webkit i386 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-webkit_4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Already tried `apt-get update` and `--fix-missing`

Comment: You appear to be using an old, unsupported version of Ubuntu (Quantal Quetzal). Please upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

To install it, Use Synaptic Package Manager.  If you don't have it installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed, open it, search for libqt4-webkit, right click on it, choose Mark for installation, and then click apply.  That will take care of all required dependences.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: How to tell `dpkg` also install all required dependences? I need `libqtwebkit4:i386 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3);
libqtwebkit4:i386 depends on libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0);
libqtwebkit4:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.4);`

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect info.  I've updated the answer with the correct info.

Comment: still no luck, here is my error https://www.dropbox.com/s/622gd7ed9ydxru3/snapshot122.png

Comment: That's not a problem, just search for that it also available, install it first, and then try again.  See [Here](https://copy.com/M3RERDRTwBhY).

Answer (score 0):

try downloading the libqt4-webkit package and install it using dpkg; It worked for me.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt4-webkit

After that fix any missing dependencies with `apt-get install -f`

Cheers.